# Isn't there a function that automatically adds the appended material?

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]

To register the appended material, I have to press 1 and 2.
If I have a lot of materials to register, it's too much work.
I looked through the options, but I couldn't find it to register at once.
Is there a way? Thank you for reading it.

Comment: if you want to automate this you'll need to write a script with python

Comment: Thank you reply. I see